# Windows Mobile & other Extensions for the UWP - which version should I use

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I have already got to know that in order to obtain DeviceId I should add reference to my project - "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP" this SDK comes with Visual Studio and is available in References Manager under Windows Universal/Extensions position.
However there are two positions like that on the list, they come with different versions - 10.0.10240.0 and 10.0.10586.0.

Which one of them should I use? Are there any differences that I should be aware of, or should I just keep using newer one? Are they related to the windows build number on the machine I want to run my app?

Answer (score 2):

A Universal Windows Platform project can use feature detection to take advantage of APIs available on a platform version "2" and still run on platform version "1", the same way it can run on desktop, mobile or IoT with specific user experience for each platform.

This is how to deal with feature detection (and not version detection)

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/

Check how to setup your project properties

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx

Comment: That's the help for the project properties page for C++ applications, not C#

Comment: well, what if i reference both versions..? will there be any confliction..?

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on References and add the Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP.

You may still need to remove the older SDK reference and do a clean build, but this resolved that error for me on the samples.

Comment: I feel like you completely misunderstood my question ;)